# difference between rows in a multi-level dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am looking to find difference between two rows in a multi-level data by iterating values within certain class and been trying different techniques by reading tutorials as I am still new to python/pandas power.

what I am trying to do is to find out difference between scores of teacher and each student in certain class.

dataframe:

```
Class, Name ,Reference, stats
    X ,SHE ,student, 30
    X ,GHE ,student, 20
    X ,GMK ,student ,10
    X ,JKO ,teacher ,50
    Y ,HHH ,student ,20
    Y ,KLP ,teacher ,30
```

Output:

```
Class,teacher, student, difference
X, JKO, SHE,20
X, JKO,GHE, 30
X, JKO, GMK, 40
Y, KLP, HHH, 10
```

Can anyone help me by guiding me towards the right direction? there can be more than 1 teachers in a class.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split your dataset into two data frames, one for students one for teachers. Then merge.

```
students = df[df.Reference == 'student'][['Class','Name','stats']]
teachers = df[df.Reference == 'teacher'][['Class','Name','stats']]

new_df = students.merge(teachers, on='Class', suffixes=('_student','_teacher'))
new_df['difference'] = new_df.stats_teacher - new_df.stats_student

print(new_df)
  Class Name_student  stats_student Name_teacher  stats_teacher  difference
0     X          SHE             30          JKO             50          20
1     X          GHE             20          JKO             50          30
2     X          GMK             10          JKO             50          40
3     Y          HHH             20          KLP             30          10
```

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code with many for loops. So there should an optimized solution than this. (Later i will try to update this solution in a better way)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("student.csv")
ref = df[df['Reference'] == 'teacher'].index.values.astype(int)
df['TeacherName'] = 'NA'
df['Difference'] = 0

for i in range(len(ref)):
    if(i == 0):
        for j in range(ref[i]+1):

            df['TeacherName'][j] = df['Name'][ref[i]]
            df['Difference'][j] = df['stats'][ref[i]] - df['stats'][j]
    else:
         for j in range(ref[i-1]+1, ref[i]):

             df['TeacherName'][j] = df['Name'][ref[i]]
             df['Difference'][j] = df['stats'][ref[i]] - df['stats'][j]

df[~ df.index.isin(ref)]
```

I'm getting the index of row for every occurrence of `df['Reference'] == 'teacher'` into a list named `ref` which will be dropped from `df` after loop statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print (df)
  Class Name Reference  stats
0     X  SHE   student     30
1     X  GHE   student     20
2     X  GMK   student     10
3     X  JKO   teacher     50
4     X  ABC   teacher    100 <-added one new row for general data
5     Y  HHH   student     20
6     Y  KLP   teacher     30

df = (df.query("Reference == 'teacher'")
          .merge(df.query("Reference == 'student'"), on='Class', suffixes=('_t','_s'))
          .assign(difference=lambda x: x['stats_t'] - x['stats_s'])
          .drop(['Reference_s','Reference_t','stats_s','stats_t'], axis=1)
          .rename(columns={'Name_s':'student','Name_t':'teacher'})
          )
print (df)
  Class teacher student  difference
0     X     JKO     SHE          20
1     X     JKO     GHE          30
2     X     JKO     GMK          40
3     X     ABC     SHE          70
4     X     ABC     GHE          80
5     X     ABC     GMK          90
6     Y     KLP     HHH          10
```

**Explanation**:

1. Filter `DataFrame` by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with `student` and `teacher` rows
2. Then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by column `Class` for all combinations in per groups
3. Then [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) new column with subtract
4. Remove unnecessary columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
5. Last `rename` columns